# How to add figure in latex file without having them on list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents

I have added four images as four pages but I dont want to have them on list of figures.How can I avoid this situation?

Comment: But you want them to have a caption "Figure X: ..."? Do the images need to be included via a floating environment (such as `table` or `figure`)? If "no" is your answer to both questions, you can just use `\includegraphics` instead of the `figure` environment around. An alternative was to put the images into individual PDF documents and include them into your LaTeX document.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! It is better to post a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). For example, A LaTeX MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. Unless the problem is a compilation error, the code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you --- and much more likely that they will!

Comment: @daniel.neumann - Actually, all you need to do is not use a \caption.

Comment: Or `\caption*` will prevent the addition the `LoF`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a normal looking caption and increment the figure numbers, but not have them appear in the list of figures, you can use the following.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mycaption}[1]% #1 = caption text
{\refstepcounter{figure}\@makecaption{\fnum@figure}{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
\mycaption{test caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\mycaption{\blindtext}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\caption{normal caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```